# Automatizando a inicialização de ambiente de desenvolvimento Ubuntu - LEMP Stack + Laravel. Como programar uma pausa entre os blocos?

Tags: ubuntu

Estou criando um código para automatizar a inicialização de um ambiente de desenvolvimento em Ubuntu (LEMP STACK). Aqui eu coloquei Servidor NginX + MariaDb + PHP7.0 + Laravel, ... , etc. A lista completa com comentários está [AQUI](https://gist.github.com/igoralves1/a1e384d56836516cfe202eab9280e9cb).

Funciona assim:

1. Usando qualquer editor (gedit por exemplo), criar um arquivo com qualquer nome e colar o código abaixo. Eu crio com o nome **sysInit**.
2. Abrir um terminal como root e rodar `source sysInit`.

Em seguida os aplicativos escolhidos são instalados um a um sem a necessidade de interação humana.

Entre um bloco de instalação e outro eu coloquei um "**clear**" para limpar o terminal. Porém eu gostaria de fazer uma pausa de alguns segundos antes de ir para o próximo bloco. Alguém poderia sugerir como fazer isso?

O código ainda não está na sua versão final, mas deixo abaixo para quem tiver interesse.
Nota: o usuário do linux é "ila". Troque "ila" por "seu usuário".

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y figlet
clear

figlet LEMP_STACK
clear

figlet TREE
sudo apt-get install -y tree
clear

figlet Only_for_virtual_machine_users
figlet VIRTUALBOX_GUEST_DKMS
sudo apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-dkms
clear

figlet Only_for_virtual_machine_users
figlet ADD_USER_TO_VBOXSF_GROUP
sudo groups ila
sudo usermod -aG vboxsf ila
sudo groups ila
clear

figlet Only_64bits
figlet GOOGLE_CHROME
sudo wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
clear

figlet SUBLIME_TEXT_3
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y sublime-text-installer
clear

figlet NGINX
sudo apt-get install -y nginx
clear

figlet PHP_7.0
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-dev
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-cgi
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-fpm
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-mbstring
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-mysql
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-curl 
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-json
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-xsl
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-intl 
#sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-php7.0
sudo apt-get install -y phpunit
clear

figlet GIT
sudo apt-get install -y git
clear
figlet GITK
sudo apt-get install -y gitk
clear
figlet GIT_GUI
sudo apt-get install -y git-gui
clear

figlet NODE_JS
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
nodejs -v
figlet MAKING_NODE_JS_TO_NODE
cd /usr/bin/
ln -s nodejs node
node -v
clear

figlet NPM
sudo apt-get install -y npm
npm -v
clear

figlet BOWER
npm install -g bower  
bower -v
clear

figlet GULP
npm install -g gulp
gulp -v
clear

//Note, the key must be constantly updated from the oficial web site https://getcomposer.org/download/ to avoid error
figlet COMPOSER
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '61069fe8c6436a4468d0371454cf38a812e451a14ab1691543f25a9627b97ff96d8753d92a00654c21e2212a5ae1ff36') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
clear

figlet JAVA_9
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y oracle-java9-installer
sudo apt-get install -y oracle-java9-set-default
java -version

figlet MYSQL_WORKBENCH
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-workbench
clear

figlet MARIA_DB_SERVER
sudo apt-get install -y mariadb-server
clear

figlet ADDING_ROOT_USER_TO_MARIA_DB
sudo mysql  -e "CREATE USER 'ila'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'ila'@'localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;select Host,User,Password from mysql.user;"
clear

figlet NODE_RED
sudo npm install -g node-red
clear
```

Então essa é aversão final do código:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y figlet
clear

figlet LEMP_STACK
sleep 5s
clear

figlet TREE
sudo apt-get install -y tree
sleep 5s
clear

figlet Only_for_virtual_machine_users
figlet VIRTUALBOX_GUEST_DKMS
sudo apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-dkms
sleep 5s
clear

figlet Only_for_virtual_machine_users
figlet ADD_USER_TO_VBOXSF_GROUP
sudo groups ila
sudo usermod -aG vboxsf ila
sudo groups ila
sleep 5s
clear

figlet Only_64bits
figlet GOOGLE_CHROME
sudo wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
sleep 5s
clear

figlet SUBLIME_TEXT_3
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y sublime-text-installer
sleep 5s
clear

figlet NGINX
sudo apt-get install -y nginx
sleep 5s
clear

figlet PHP_7.0
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-dev
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-cgi
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-fpm
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-mbstring
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-mysql
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-curl 
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-json
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-xsl
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-intl 
#sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-php7.0
sudo apt-get install -y phpunit
sleep 5s
clear

figlet GIT
sudo apt-get install -y git
sleep 5s
clear

figlet GITK
sudo apt-get install -y gitk
sleep 5s
clear

figlet GIT_GUI
sudo apt-get install -y git-gui
sleep 5s
clear

figlet NODE_JS
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
nodejs -v
sleep 5s

figlet MAKING_NODE_JS_TO_NODE
cd /usr/bin/
ln -s nodejs node
node -v
sleep 5s
clear

figlet NPM
sudo apt-get install -y npm
npm -v
sleep 5s
clear

figlet BOWER
npm install -g bower  
bower -v
sleep 5s
clear

figlet GULP
npm install -g gulp
gulp -v
sleep 5s
clear

//Note, the key must be constantly updated from the oficial web site https://getcomposer.org/download/ to avoid error
figlet COMPOSER
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '61069fe8c6436a4468d0371454cf38a812e451a14ab1691543f25a9627b97ff96d8753d92a00654c21e2212a5ae1ff36') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
sleep 5s
clear

figlet JAVA_9
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y oracle-java9-installer
sudo apt-get install -y oracle-java9-set-default
java -version
sleep 5s
clear

figlet MYSQL_WORKBENCH
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-workbench
sleep 5s
clear

figlet MARIA_DB_SERVER
sudo apt-get install -y mariadb-server
sleep 5s
clear

figlet ADDING_ROOT_USER_TO_MARIA_DB
sudo mysql  -e "CREATE USER 'ila'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'ila'@'localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;select Host,User,Password from mysql.user;"
sleep 5s
clear

figlet NODE_RED - IoT
sudo npm install -g node-red
sleep 5s
clear
```

Comment: Tu pode colocar um sleep, mas não faz muito sentido reinventar a roda. Já existem muitos scripts que fazem isso prontos, temos recipes de puppet, chef, containers docker, etc que já fazem praticamente tudo isso.

Comment: oi @gmsantos. Eu estou usando esse script para aulas. Alunos iniciantes no linux. Com certza docker é uma melhor opção num ambiente profissional.

Comment: @gmsantos a sua resposta deu certo. Fiz sleep 5s. Poste a resposta.